# Trying to getCurrentUrl() and open it in new tab in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have to get the url and open it in 3 new tabs. But I get errors while trying:

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {
        browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('t').perform();
        browser.sleep(2000);
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[ 1 ]); // 0 or 1 to switch between the 2 open windows  //  // 
        browser.get(url)
     
      });
    });
```

Error:   `Failed: null value in entry: name=null`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

These are limitation with chrome driver to simulate the same behavior at browser level. It means sendKeys doesn't work with opening new tab as you are trying in your code. There is an alternative way to achieve your goal by **'window.open()'**. here is your code snippet with small modification. hope this helps you.

```
     browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {
            browser.executeScript('window.open()').then( () => {
            browser.sleep(2000);
            browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            browser.switchTo().window(handles[ 1 ]); // 0 or 1 to switch between the 2 open windows  //  // 
            browser.get(url);
          });
      });
   });
```